# django ActiveSession MultipleObjectsReturned

Tags: django, authentication

Every now and then I get complaints from users that they are unable to login.
I see the following exception in debug.log.
The database table authentication_activeSession has two entries for the user's session.

The offending line of code is

```
 session = ActiveSession.objects.get(user=user)
```

How should this be countered?

```
 File "/home/admin/site/django-api/api/submissions/viewsets/sitesubmissions.py", line 19, in create
    session = ActiveSession.objects.get(user=user)
  File "/home/siteadmin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/siteadmin/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 439, in get
    raise self.model.MultipleObjectsReturned(
api.authentication.models.active_session.ActiveSession.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one ActiveSession -- it returned 2!
```

Comment: There are more ActiveSession with user=[the user you give it]. If you want to get all sessions, then use ActiveSession.objects.filter.

Comment: It looks like they are logging in from Chrome and Edge. This is resulting two entries in the db table. How do I use filter and get only one session back?

Comment: You can filter the sessions based on additional criteria such as an auto-generated key. Also, then you need to add it to your model and somehow save in browser to retrieve the session by it later (probably save it in cookies).